# C# Как сделать так, чтобы значение кнопки вводилось в выбранный текстбокс? Как установить фокус на нужный TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть панель с кнопками, два текстбокса. При запуске формы я нажимаю на текстбокс логина, после нажимаю кнопку, чтобы ввести цифру. Но этого не происходит. Как сделать так, чтобы значение кнопки вводилось в выбранный текстбокс?

На C# программирую недавно (как и ожидалось). Возможно, я делаю совсем не то, что нужно, но в интернете я ничего подобного не нашла. Спасибо!

```
        private void Cl_tl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //событие нажатия на клавишу 0
        {
        Button B = (Button)sender; //присваивание переменной b значение текущей нажатой кнопки

        if (Log.IsFocused) // если фокус установлен на текстовое поле логина, то прибавить символ к текущей строке текстбокса логина
        {
            Log.Text += B.Content; 
            Log.Focus();
        }
        if (Pas.IsFocused) //аналогично с текстбоксом пароля
        {
            Pas.Password += B.Content;
            Pas.Focus();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: А другие кнопки вы подписали на событие Cl_tl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

Comment: если это учебное приложение, то поглядите в сторону MVVM

Comment: 1)На момент создания я делала только одну кнопку для проверки.

Comment: 2) Учебное приложение, но в колледже нас этому не учат. Делаю курсовую, решила попутно изучать язык С#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что событие фокуса распространяется на любой `UIElement`, кликнутая кнопка может стать элементом, который ожидает ввода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому выцеплять фокусированный элемент из окна - не вариант, так как он постоянно меняется и останавливается на кликнутом элементе.

- Вариант 1. Использовать свойства FocusManager.

`FocusManager` - предоставляет набор статических методов и свойств для определения областей фокуса и для установки имеющих фокус элементов в данной области.

`UIElement` "управляется" `FocusManager`-ом, и они имеют ряд прикрепляемых свойств.

Нам необходимо свойство `FocusManager.IsFocusScope` - оно определяет, является ли элемент областью "независимой" фокусировки. По умолчанию общую группу фокусировки определяют элементы `Window`, `Menu`, `ToolBar` и `ContextMenu`.

Определим области фокуса. В нашем случае это область текстовых полей и область цифровой клавиатуры. Так как с неё планируется ввод только в текстовые поля, можно определить общий контейнер для них. и определим свойство `FocusManager.IsFocusScope` для него.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь эта область запоминает фокус вне зависимости от других областей.

А для кнопок определим обработчик. Так как в примере используется ещё и `PasswordBox`, то необходима дополнительная типизация.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Получаем элемент, на котором находится фокус в определённой
    //нами группе
    var a = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(sp);
    //Если элемента нет - завершаем обработку
    if (a == null) return;

    //Получаем данные из кнопки
    var b = sender as Button;
    //пытаемся типизировать фокус-элемент
    var c = a as TextBox;
    //Если получилось
    if (c != null)
    {
        //Добавляем данные к блоку
        c.Text += b.Content;
        return;
    }
    //Иначе - это PasswordBox
    ((PasswordBox)a).Password += b.Content;
}
```

Всё работает. Можно проверять.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Вариант 2. Простой

Так как фокус работает в пределах `Window`, можно сделать ссылку на поле, которое получило фокус и сохранять её в переменной.

Так как в примере используется два разных по типу поля, можно сохранить ссылку на переменную, которая имеет тип, общий для `TextBox` и `PasswordBox`, и это `Control`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
//Переменная, которая хранит ссылку на сфокусированный элемент
Control current_focus;

//Общий обработчик для необходимых полей
private void FocusEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    current_focus = (Control)sender;
}
```

После этого, так же типизируем в обработчике нажатия кнопки.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var b = sender as Button;
    var c = current_focus as TextBox;
    if (c != null)
    {
        c.Text += b.Content;
        return;
    }
    ((PasswordBox)current_focus).Password += b.Content;
}
```

Всё работает точно так же, но логичнее и понятнее кажется вариант 1.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Прошло три года... Пролетели как мимолётное видение... Я даже не знала, какой ужасный код я писала и какой ответ дала сама себе тогда. В знак извинений, я удалила предыдущий ответ и заменила его этим. Спасибо, мама. Я в телевизоре!

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Внутри вашего обработчика `Cl_tl` `Log.IsFocused == false` и `Pas.IsFocused == false`, т.к. фокус в этот момент уже на кнопке.

Подпишитесь на `GotFocus` у `Log` и `Pas`, запомните последнее активное поле в члене класса и используйте его в обработчике клика.